# whay zero is not consider by %d identifier

Tags: matlab, identifier

I Have 400 files in my directory. Which have file name H1001,H1002,H1003....like that. I want to read that files in matlab

When I m using that code it give me the error.

```
'd=dir('C:\Users\Desktop\New\*.txt')>


<num_files=length(d)>

data=cell(1,num_files);

for k = 1:400

myfilename = sprintf('H1%3d.txt',k);

mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);

end'
```

it is showing

`myfilename=H1  1`. which is wrong file name H1001. so GETTING ERROR IN NEXT LINE.

It is not reading 00. It gives blank space.

Can any body tell me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format string if you want a zero filled right adjusted value is not `%3d` (which right adjusts with spaces) but instead `%03d`;

```
for k = 1:400
  myfilename = sprintf('H1%03d.txt',k);
  mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);
end
```

The difference can easily be seen in

```
> printf('H1%3d.txt\n', 7);
H1  7.txt

> printf('H1%03d.txt\n', 7);
H1007.txt
```

Comment: @RahulKumarVijay If the answer helped with your problem, please consider accepting it using the check mark to the left of the answer. That will allow others will similar problems to more easily find the solution.